# How to handle update_all when empty data returned

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am updating some of my database details using update all. When the returned data is empty update all fails ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: Unknown column

I know this can be fixed for example, but this looks like a redundant use, because in my code base I am doing many changes as follows

```
Product.where(local_product: true).update_all(tax: 0) if Product.where(local_product: true).present?
```

I wish if update_all had handled this by itself, or is there any other way?

Comment: It handles by itself. You can just cut the `if` clause

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just do it in one line you dont need to check if there are any records.

`Product.where(local_product: true).update_all(tax: 0)` will generates next sql query:

```
UPDATE "products" SET "tax" = true WHERE "products"."local_product" = true
```

Database filters records for you, you dont need to check it twice, if there are no data for update it will do nothing.

Answer (score -1):

Try this to avoid redundant

```
@products = Product.where(local_product: true)
@products.update_all(tax: 0) if @products.present?
```

Comment: This just the same as in OP question.